# Binding Text property with ApplicationBarIconButton in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to bind the string to Text Property in ApplicationBarIconButton in WP7.
While doing this, I got an error as

**Set property 'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.Text' threw an exception.**

StackTrace:

> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.InternalSetValue(PropertyInfo
>   thisProperty, Object obj, Object value, Object[] index,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
>               at MS.Internal.XamlMemberInfo.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
>               at MS.Internal.XamlManagedRuntimeRPInvokes.SetValue(XamlTypeToken inType,
>   XamlQualifiedObject& inObj, XamlPropertyToken inProperty,
>   XamlQualifiedObject& inValue)
>               at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_LoadComponentNative(IntPtr
>   pContext, IntPtr pComponent, UInt32 cUriStringLength, String
>   uriString, UInt32 cXamlStrLength, Byte* pXamlStr, UInt32
>   cAssemblyStrLength, String assemblyStr)
>               at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Application_LoadComponent(IManagedPeerBase
>   componentAsDO, String resourceLocator, UnmanagedMemoryStream stream,
>   UInt32 numBytesToRead, String assemblyString)
>               at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
>               at Syncfusion.Phone.Tools.Controls.TimeSpanPickerPage.InitializeComponent()
>               at Syncfusion.Phone.Tools.Controls.TimeSpanPickerPage..ctor()
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeConstructorInfo
>   rtci, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean
>   verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
>               at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback
>   userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
>               at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_0(Object
>   args)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly
>   caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>               at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>               at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
>               at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>               at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
>               at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>               at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority
>   priority)
>               at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
>               at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
>               at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
>               at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle,
>   Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)

**Solution:** The ApplicationBar is a special element that is not implemented in Silverlight and cannot be used with databinding. You'll have to directly update the Text property in C#. Peter Torr explains it here: Peter Torr's Blog > [Why are the ApplicationBar objects not FrameworkElements?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/06/18/why-are-the-applicationbar-objects-not-frameworkelements.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me you already know the answer, anyhow binding data the ApplicationBar is not possible, you can create the application bar at runtime though, you might be able to do something from there. [ApplicationBarIconButton At Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbariconbutton%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Not like that, I asked question here, and continued searching that time found answer so posted here. Thank you.

Comment: Glad You did :). 
you should consider the runtime creation though.

Comment: Yes, i got what i expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Although the ApplicationBar is not a bindable object, there are workarouds to make binding work.

One, is the `ApplicationBarBehavior` from the [Cimbalino Windows Phone Toolkit](https://github.com/PedroLamas/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit) (you can [get it from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit))!